# How to make a String from JSON object?

Tags: java, json, string

I'm trying to get the "definition" String out of the following JSON snippet:

```
{
      "headword": "Google",
      "senses": [
        {
          "definition": [
            "a very popular search enginecomputer program that allows you to search for information on the Internet. Google also provides other Internet services including e-mail, maps, social networking, and video sharing."
          ]
        }
      ],
      "datasets": [
        "ldoce5",
        "dictionary"
      ],
      "id": "cqAFJKTgNJ",
      "url": "/v2/dictionaries/entries/cqAFJKTgNJ",
      "pronunciations": [
        {
          "audio": [
            {
              "lang": "British English",
              "type": "pronunciation",
              "url": "/v2/dictionaries/assets/ldoce/gb_pron/google1004.mp3"
            },
            {
              "lang": "American English",
              "type": "pronunciation",
              "url": "/v2/dictionaries/assets/ldoce/us_pron/google1004a.mp3"
            }
          ],
          "ipa": "ˈɡuːɡəl"
        }
      ]
    }
```

The problem is that in the current JSON snippet "definition" appears to be an JSONObject and, whenever I try to make it String, I get an Error saying that it isn't a String. When I just leave an object as is, the output includes brackets and other symbols:

`{"definition":["a very popular search enginecomputer program that allows you to search for information on the Internet. Google also provides other Internet services including e-mail, maps, social networking, and video sharing."]}`

Is there a way to make a nice and neat String that would contain exact definition and nothing more. Btw, using [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) library.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity {

private static String word;


public static void wordInitializer() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    word = reader.readLine();
}

public static void processing() throws Exception {

    String path = "http://api.pearson.com/v2/dictionaries/ldoce5/entries?headword=" + word;        
    URL url = new URL(path);

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());
    String line = "";
    while (scanner.hasNext())
        line += scanner.nextLine();
    scanner.close();

    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(line);

    JSONObject results = obj.getJSONArray("results").getJSONObject(0);
    JSONArray senses = results.getJSONArray("senses");
    String definition = senses.getJSONObject(0).toString();
    System.out.println(definition);
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    wordInitializer();
    processing();
}
```

Comment: where is your code

Comment: It's a JSON array with a single element, a JSON string. Please see the JSON format [here](http://json.org/).

Comment: definition is an element in the json holding an array....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at the `senses` array we see that it contains an object wich in turn has one key `definition` which is also an array. The first element in that array is what you want, to get that you'd do it like this:

```
String definition = senses.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("definition").getString(0);
```

Comment: @MaximMaliarov Then would you mind accepting the anwser? ;)

Answer (score 1):

It is a JSON array, not a String. The square braces gives this away. You should parse it as an array and then obtain the first element to get the definition.

Comment: Also worth noting that most of the other pieces of data in this response are also arrays.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. Will try this solution, just dived in JSON, so don't really understand things.